# Prove that there exist a sylow subgroup of $G$ which is fixed by $\alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\alpha\in Aut(G)$ such that $\alpha$ restricted to any sylow subgroup of $G$ equals the restriction of some inner automorphism of $G$ and $(o(\alpha),o(G))=1$, then is it true that there exist a sylow subgroup of $G$ which is fixed by $\alpha$.

I think this is true, but could not think of proper reasoning. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "...such that α restricted to any Sylow subgroup of $G$ lies in $Inn(G)$ ..." By this, you mean that if $\alpha$ is an automorphism of a Sylow subgroup of $G$ then it is an inner automorphism of $G$?

Comment: I don't understand that part either.

Comment: @vnd plz see edit....

Comment: I agree with the remarks of @vnd. If you mean that $(S^g)^{\alpha}=(S^{\alpha})^{g^{\alpha}}$, for any Sylow subgroup $S$ and $\alpha \in Aut(G)$, then you statement is correct. It follows from a lemma of Glauberman on coprime group actions, in combination with the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, see for example M.I. Isaacs, Finite Group Theory, Lemma 3.24 and Theorem 3.23.

Comment: But if the orders of $\alpha$ and $G$ are coprime, then you don't need the condition about the restriction of $\alpha$ to Sylow subgroups being inner. By the Frattini Argument and Schur-Zassenhaus  in $G \rtimes  \langle \alpha \rangle$, every Sylow subgroup is fixed by a conjugate of $\alpha$, and so $\alpha$ fixes a Sylow subgroup.